# Adding XmlAttribute to XmlAttributeCollection

Tags: c#, xml, xmlattributecollection

I want to create an XmlAttributeCollection and add some attributes depending on conditions. This is what I've tried.

```
XmlElement fishElement = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "fi", string.Empty);
XmlAttributeCollection attCollection = AddExtraAttributes(doc,condition);
foreach (XmlAttribute attribute in attCollection)
   {
      fishElement.Attributes.Append((XmlAttribute)attribute.Clone());
   }

private XmlAttributeCollection AddExtraAttributes(XmlDocument doc,bool condition)
{
    XmlAttributeCollection xmlAttributeCollection;
    if(condition)
     {
        XmlAttribute attribute = doc.CreateAttribute("A");
        attribute.Value = "value1";
        xmlAttributeCollection.Append(attribute);
     }
    else
     {
        XmlAttribute attribute = doc.CreateAttribute("B");
        attribute.Value = "value2";
        xmlAttributeCollection.Append(attribute);
     }
   return xmlAttributeCollection;
}
```

But this way, I encounter this error:

> xmlAttributeCollection might not be initialized before accessing

And if i try to do this:

```
XmlAttributeCollection xmlAttributeCollection = new XmlAttributeCollection;
```

It says:

> Cannot access internal constructor 'XmlAttributeCollection' here

So how can I make it works?

**Update**

So I've solved the problem this way

```
XmlAttribute newAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("genre");
newAttr.Value = "novel";
XmlAttributeCollection attrColl = doc.DocumentElement.Attributes;
attrColl.Append(newAttr);
```

But now everytime I call `AddExtraAttributes`, `xmlAttributeCollection` has some extra attributes and I can't set it to null (`xmlAttributeCollection=null`) before I run my method again. because then I can't run `xmlAttributeCollection.append`.

So How can I reset `xmlAttributeCollection` before adding attributes to it all over again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlattributecollection.append%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

I don't know if there's a better one out there.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<book ISBN='1-861001-57-5'>" +
            "<title>Pride And Prejudice</title>" +
            "</book>");      

//Create a new attribute.
XmlAttribute newAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("genre");
newAttr.Value = "novel";

//Create an attribute collection and add the new attribute 
//to the collection.
XmlAttributeCollection attrColl = doc.DocumentElement.Attributes;
attrColl.Append(newAttr);
```

**Update**

As a solution for my *second problem* I used a list of `XmlAttribute`s so that I can create a new instance everytime I call the method. Now the whole code looks like this:

```
XmlElement fishElement = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "fi", string.Empty);
IEnumerable<XmlAttribute> attCollection = AddExtraAttributes(doc,condition);
foreach (XmlAttribute attribute in attCollection)
   {
      fishElement.Attributes.Append(attribute);
   }

private IEnumerable<XmlAttribute> AddExtraAttributes(XmlDocument doc,bool condition)
{
    List<XmlAttribute> xmlAttributeCollection = new List<XmlAttribute>();
    if(condition)
     {
        XmlAttribute attribute = doc.CreateAttribute("A");
        attribute.Value = "value1";
        xmlAttributeCollection.Add(attribute);
     }
    else
     {
        XmlAttribute attribute = doc.CreateAttribute("B");
        attribute.Value = "value2";
        xmlAttributeCollection.Add(attribute);
     }
   return xmlAttributeCollection;
}
```